# List of file types that generate a thumbnail preview?

Tags: files, content, preview

Is there a list of file types/extensions that Salesforce create a preview of?

ie. when using `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=${versionId}`

For context, I'm creating my own file previewer, and for file types that don't have a preview I want to handle it differently.

It's a bit of an XY problem, but if I know the file extensions that Salesforce will generate a thumbnail for, it will make things a lot simpler.

At the moment I have this simple list:

- jpg
- jpeg
- pdf
- png
- docx

Comment: Well you can simply check if servlet.shepherd returns a preview. Because it is quite common that the preview is MEANT to work but it couldn't generate (processing queue busy, file corrupt etc. etc.)

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the things I've tried, but there are circumstances where it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_preview.htm&type=5).

*The Preview tab displays if your file is one of the following types:*

- Microsoft® Office 97 through Microsoft Office 2007 Word, Excel, and
  PowerPoint. Some Microsoft Office 2007 features don’t display
  correctly in previews.
- Adobe® PDF. Copy-protected PDFs can't be previewed.
- JPG, BMP, GIF, and PNG.